# WARN [org.jboss.modules] (default task-34) Failed to define class in wildfly 10

Tags: java, module, installation, wildfly-10

I have created a custom jar **(platts-custom.jar)** and i have installed that jar as wildfly modules.

However the main application i.e. ear file is being deployed using normal deployment i.e. inside **standalone/deployments** folder.

There are some dependent jars required for **platts-custom.jar** which are available in ear file.

During server start i dont see any error but when i try to access the functionality for the platts-custom.jar i see the below error :

Please can you help here ??

```
2017-09-11 07:39:29,272 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (default task-34) Failed to define class com.datagenic.platts.functions.ReCalcAlok in Module "com.datagenic.platts.platts-custom:main" from local module loader @80169cf (finder: local module finder @5427c60c (roots: D:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final_For_Oracle\platts\..\modules,D:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final_For_Oracle\platts\..\modules\system\layers\base,D:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final_For_Oracle\platts\datagenic\modules)): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/datagenic/platts/functions/ReCalcAlok (Module "com.datagenic.platts.platts-custom:main" from local module loader @80169cf (finder: local module finder @5427c60c (roots: D:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final_For_Oracle\platts\..\modules,D:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final_For_Oracle\platts\..\modules\system\layers\base,D:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final_For_Oracle\platts\datagenic\modules))): com/datagenic/formulaparser/functions/base/BaseFunction
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:606)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.datagenic.formulaparser.RunFormula.execute(RunFormula.java:323)
    at com.datagenic.formulaparser.RunFormula.parse(RunFormula.java:96)
    at com.datagenic.formulaparser.RunFormula.parseTimeSeries(RunFormula.java:144)
    at com.datagenicgroup.data.Function.execute(Function.java:398)
    at com.datagenicgroup.data.Function.execute(Function.java:468)
    at com.datagenic.data.DataActionsService.getGenicDataForFormulaProperties(DataActionsService.java:606)
    at com.datagenic.data.DataActionsService.getFormulaData(DataActionsService.java:921)
    at com.datagenic.data.DataActionsService.getGenicDataForFormula(DataActionsService.java:473)
    at com.datagenic.data.ws.DataActionsWebService.getGenicDataForFormula(DataActionsWebService.java:269)
    at com.datagenic.data.ws.DataActionsWebService$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.getGenicDataForFormula$$super(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)   

2017-09-11 07:39:29,293 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (default task-34) Interceptor for {http://www.datagenicgroup.com}DataActionsService#{http://www.datagenicgroup.com}getGenicDataForFormula has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Failed to link com/datagenic/platts/functions/ReCalcAlok (Module "com.datagenic.platts.platts-custom:main" from local module loader @80169cf (finder: local module finder @5427c60c (roots: D:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final_For_Oracle\platts\..\modules,D:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final_For_Oracle\platts\..\modules\system\layers\base,D:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final_For_Oracle\platts\datagenic\modules))): com/datagenic/formulaparser/functions/base/BaseFunction
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:144)
```

Comment: Did you add a module dependency on your deployment for your module? This documentation may help as well https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins thanks a lot for your time. Yes I have added the module dependency. Upon further investigation i can see the below : I have a class in custom module ReCalcAlok which is extending another class BaseFunction present in a jar that is included in ear/lib folder. There is no error at server start up. But when I use Class.forName() inside my application above error is coming up. It looks like the custom module class loader could not access the jar present in ear/lib folder. Not sure what is wrong here

Comment: You're module cannot have a dependency on your deployment. So if the module needs in a class supplied by your deployment it won't work.